# Get Random value from key value pair using Groovy scripting

Tags: jmeter

I have a key value pair

def mp = [ 'QLD': 'Brisbane','NSW': 'Sydney','NT': 'Darwin']
I can get specific value using mp.get("QLD"). But how can we get a random value from dictionary?. Can you please help in this regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
mp[mp.keySet().asList().get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0,mp.keySet().size()))]
```

- `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0,mp.keySet().size()` - get random index of keys using [RandomUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html)
- `mp.keySet().asList().get()` - get key name by index
- `mp[]` - get value

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)